# Android - heads up notifications issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having troubles getting heads up notifications working on android. Does anyone have any idea about what is missing to make them appear on my emulator ? I've read a lot of topics concerning heads up notifications and everything I tried didn't work. Thanks in advance

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "channelInality";
            String description = "channelDescription";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(mNotificationChannel, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.enableVibration(true);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = InalityAppController.getInstance().getContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    public void createNotification(String pTitle, String pContent) {

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(InalityAppController.getInstance().getContext());

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(InalityAppController.getInstance().getContext(), mNotificationChannel);
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_people);
        notification.setContentTitle(pTitle);
        notification.setContentText(pContent);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        notification.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            notification.setVibrate(new long[0]);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationID, notification.build());
        mNotificationID++;
    }
```

Comment: So, you said you read a lot about Android notifications, but did you read [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) from the Android docs? I think if the tutorial is followed, the notification should work.

Comment: How are you invoking these methods. What is the value assigned to mNotificationID

Comment: @Psypher I’m invoking them through a button, just for testing. The thing is that notifications are well pushed in the « Notification Center » (when swiping down the screen), but they are not displayed heads up when receiving them

Comment: @LAD basic notification work, yes. I followed this documentation. But only basic notifications, not heads up notifications. That’s the reason of my post

Comment: what is the mobile OS u are testing this on..hope its android 5 above, as this works only above android 5+

Comment: @Psypher Android 7.1